# why does this on() trigger right away instead of just binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having some problems with `.on()` and how to use it instead of `.bind()` in this situation. 
What im trying to do here is i click a link and that is supose to bind another click event, but instead it triggers that event right away. I looked in the documentation/jquery.js file and this is how im suppose to do it.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bNaFV/

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function(){    
    $('#show_me').addClass('remain');

    //this is only suppose to bind that next time i click anywhere on the document it should hide
    // not right away
    $(document).on('click', 'html', function(){
      $('#show_me').hide();        
    });
});

$("#click_me").hover(
  function () {
    $('#show_me').show();
  }, 
  function () {
      if ($('#show_me').hasClass('remain')){
           return;   
      } else {
          $('#show_me').hide();   
      }
  }
);



<a href="#" id="click_me">click me</a><br /><br />

<div id="show_me"></div>​
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the event:

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function(e){    
    e.stopPropagation(); //Stop the event from bubbling further
    $('#show_me').addClass('remain');
    $(document).on('click', 'html', function(){
        $('#show_me').hide();        
    });
});
```

This is because the event has been captured at the `#click_me` element. You then bind an event handler for that same event type somewhere higher up the DOM tree. The event then continues bubbling up the tree and reaches the `document`, where it triggers the new event handler.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bNaFV/5/).

**Update** (see comments)

As noted by @zerkms in the comments, I think you probably only want to bind the event handler to `document` once. You could use the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to do so, which unbinds the event handler after it's been executed once:

```
$(document).one('click', 'html', function(){
    $('#show_me').hide();        
});
```

Comment: Was about to post this - here's a fiddle to show it works: http://jsfiddle.net/bNaFV/3/

Comment: Also I'd add that OP only needs to bind to `document` `click` just once, not each `click_me` click (or at least unbind it)

Comment: @James Allardice: oh, thank you for `.one()` (though I never needed it really, but still good to know something new), +1

Comment: @zerkms - Yeah `one` can be really useful. For some reason it seems to be one of those jQuery methods that few people have heard of. I didn't know about it until someone else mentioned it in an answer.

Comment: Yes i thought of the `.one()` but im gone do more checkes once its clicked if other elements got classes and so on. Thanks for the well put answer.